# Add sslAllowInvalidHostnames option in Intellij or MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to connect to a Mongo database via Intellij or Compass (either would do) with ssh and ssl. I need the sslAllowInvalidHostnames option for that, but can't find where and how to configure them. Anyone knows how to configure it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to add it on "Advanced" tab of datasource settings?

Comment: Yes, I have sslAllowInvalidHostnames as name with value true